# Lib GDX exported jar file does not detect assets

Tags: java, libgdx

so I built a jar file of my lib gdx project using the console command `gradlew desktop:dist` and it builds successfully. When I try to run it the program immediately crashes so I run it with a command line to get the console output and it seems that none of the assets are found so it fails. I use eclipse and it runs perfectly fine in the IDE, yes I set up properly my assets folder in my IDE and hooked it up to the build path and the strangest part about this is that if I open the exported jar file it actually contains all of my assets as it should. I run this code to get it:

```
FileHandle test = Gdx.files.internal("levels/default/level1.png");
        if (test.exists())
            System.err.println("exists!");
```

And of course, it does not find the file even though that exact directory exists and leads to the proper asset inside the jar file itself. Why is this not working, I also tried using the built-in java File type to get the file and it works fine in the IDE itself but the same problem with the exported jar.

Comment: What error do you get when your app crashes?

Comment: It is my own thrown error that happens when there is no levels loaded and it makes a call at start up to load the levels in assets/levels/default/level.png, if this file does not exist then my error is thrown which is what is happening. As I said in the post, inside the IDE it works fine but just the exported jar has problems and the path exists inside the jar so it is not with me calling the wrong file path or anything.

Comment: For anyone to help you, you will need to create a [mcve] that illustrates the problem. I understand the general idea behind what you are doing and the problem you encountered, but it is impossible to figure out the cause without some code to work with.